# How to concatenate huge number of files

Tags: unix, concatenation, cat

I would like to concatenate my files. I use

```
cat *txt > newFile
```

But I have almost 500000 files and it complains that the

```
argument list is too long.
```

Is there an efficient and fast way of merging half a million files?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your directory structure is shallow (there are no subdirectories) then you can simply do:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \; > newFile
```

If you have subdirectories, you can limit the find to the top level, or you might consider putting some of the files in the sub-directories so you don't have this problem!

This is not particularly efficient, and some versions of find allow you to do:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \+ > newFile
```

for greater efficiency.  (Note the backslash before the `+` is not necessary, but I find it nice for symmetry with the previous example.)

Comment: thanks. Where do I mention the file extension? i do not want to cat all but only certain files (*txt for example). I do not have subdirectories.

Comment: You can limit the search with `-name`.  For example, if you only want .txt files, use `find . -name '*.txt' ...`.  See the documentation for `find` for details.

Comment: comparing the suggested approach with `for i in ls;do cat $i >> newFile` on `10 files` each `10GB`, gives a `50 seconds` profit to the latter approach; test case done on single node server `(2.1 GHz, single processor; Intel Xeon, 4 cores)`.

Comment: note that this solution does not concatenate the files in some predicatable order, let alone in the same order as the shell's wild card expansion of the question would produce.

Answer (score 4):

How about doing it in a loop:

```
for a in *.txt ; do cat $a >> newFile ; done
```

This has the disadvantage of spawning a new `cat` instance for each file, which might be costly, but if the files are reasonably large the I/O overhead should dominate over the CPU time required to spawn a new process.

I would recommend creating a file containing the files in the proper order, I'm not 100% sure about the guarantees of using globbing like this (and like in the question).

Comment: I'd recommend this approach for big files merge; slightly faster than `cat` used with `find`.

Comment: I would suggest to place the redirection to newfile after the loop, so that the process does not have to search for the end of newfile in each iteration. Like this : `for a in *.txt ; do cat $a; done  > newFile`

Comment: Wouldn't this also generate an "argument list is too long" error?  Using `find` or `xargs` avoids this error.