# Concatenate huge amount of files in chunks using zsh

Tags: zsh

Im trying to solve a efficient way of concatenating a huge amount(2 millions) of text files in chunks of 100k files.

For now i have

```
!#/usr/bin/zsh
a=0
b=0
for file in ./dir/*.txt
do
    let a+=1
    cat "$file" >> $results$b.txt
    if (($a>10000))
    then
        let b+=1
        let a=0
    fi
done
```

I cant figure how can imake chuks in a "fast" way? This code in my machine takes around 2 minutes for chunk, and need to do around 200 chunks, so around 7 hours. Its a thing that i need to do it once, so its not the end of the world, but i like to learn and think better and do it in a more efficient way.

Thx

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695105/how-to-concatenate-huge-number-of-files

Comment: its not the same question. How i make chunks of it?

Comment: I think you mean `cat "$file">> $results$b.txt`. The extra `|` should generate an error message. As is your code is a pretty good solution. You could look to use gnu-parallel to run multiple copies of the script, but likely writing many of the output files at the same time onto one harddrive will cause inefficient write times. Edit your Q to show `time yourscript anyArgs` for one loop on `$b`. Good luck.

Comment: yes! that was a type error when i paste here!. It still running. When its ends i put the time.

Comment: One approach would be to use GNU parallel and GNU split: `parallel 'cat | split -b 100000' ::: *.txt`

Comment: Are you using bash or zsh (though I doubt it will matter for any answers, but you should tag appropriately)?

Comment: And are the files approximately the same size, and please edit your Q to show the size of the average file. Good luck.

Comment: Too bad the downvoters didn't explain what is wrong with this Q (they will probably not look at it again, so we'll never know). For an early Q, this has shown a meaningful attempt to solve your problem and includes some code (gasp!). I don't get it. Sorry for the bad reception and wish you luck solving your problem .

Comment: Maybe you should do a "back of the envelope calculation" on how long it will take to process your 2million + files, and show it to your manager. They may be happy with your prediction.  If you expect to be doing this every day, and you require it to run 10X faster, then you're going to have to go with more hardware and network bandwidth to solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: On regular spinning disk hardware, you can estimate that you can write 1GB per minute.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you're looking for decent performance with that many files, I wouldn't use a shell script.

(Untested) perl that should join up files like you want:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $nfiles = 0;
my $n = 0;
my $out;

while (my $file = glob "./dir/*.txt") {
    if ($nfiles++ % 100000 == 0) {
        open $out, ">:raw", "results$n.txt"
            or die "Unable to open results$n.txt: $!\n";
        $n += 1;
    }
    open my $tmp, "<:raw", $file or die "Unable to open $file: $!\n";
    print $out do { local $/; <$tmp> };
}
```

Comment: Thx, but i try it, and the first chunk it did it really fast, and then was reaaaaly slow.